# Ionic application shows localhost:8080 in chrome inspect

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, google-chrome-devtools, ionic-native, ionic-view

beginner in ionic technology. Facing issue after creating project
    ionic start Myapp blank 
    ionic cordova run android

```
@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.2
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.0
```

global packages:

```
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.11
Cordova Platforms  : android 7.0.0
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
```

System:

```
Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1
Node              : v8.11.2
npm               : 5.6.0
OS                : Windows 10
```

Environment Variables:

```
ANDROID_HOME : C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
```

Misc:

```
backend : pro.
```

After running the application to inspect using android device.
chrome://inspect/#devices Following differences are there ! 
[image]

Above image and URL starts with localhost:8080

here in below image URL starts with file:///android_asset/www/index.html

[image]

How to get URL as file:///android_asset/www/index.html in every ionic projects using chrome inspect instead of localhost:8080?

Due to this issue Facing issue like :
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 400.

Comment: Did you manage to figure out why it's showing localhost in the dev tools instead of the file path: file:///android_asset/www...?

Comment: @HamzaIshak : yes, because of the cordova-plugin-ionic-webview.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The above issue resolved by following command

```
project directory>ionic cordova plugin remove cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 
project directory>ionic cordova run android
```

and check in chrome://inspect it will connect with file:///android_asset it will work !!
Happy coding

Answer (score 2):

Removing `cordova-plugin-ionic-webview` has side effects, especially if you also want to deploy the same app for iOS.

The actual solution for your problem is to return the correct `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header in the backend application you are trying to access.

You didn't provide the information, but I guess it was an `OPTIONS` requests as well that your backend isn't configured to respond to correctly which is why you received the http status code 400. Your backend should also handle those and return a `200 OK`.